# Kestrel: error if I use URL with non-ASCII characters

Tags: url, asp.net-core, .net-standard, non-ascii-characters, kestrel

I'm using Kestrel for hosting my ASP.Net Core web apps. I need to use special charachters (non-ASCII) in the URL.

If I use IIS Express in the Visual Studio I can use non-ASCII characters in the URL. If I use Kestrel I can't use it. Can I configure Kestrel so that I can use non-ASCII characters in the URL?

If not: is there a way in .NET Standard 1.4 to encode a unicode URL to an ASCII URL?

Thank you in forward.

Regards
Matthias

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I only get an 400 Bad Request

Comment: There will be far more information available than just that. What is the content of the 400 error?

Comment: I know. I also need more information. But there is not more information in the content. By the way I'm using Postman to call the Web Service.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and use it to get more info.

Comment: I'm already using it. I think that he doesn't reach the HttpGet-method...

Comment: Without more detail, I can't help I'm afraid.

Comment: Now I noticed that this error only occurs with Postman. If I use Firefox to call the Web Service it works.

Comment: If I use Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome it also works...

Answer (score 0):

In general, any special characters should be urlencoded. That is the only safe way to include them in the URL. Specifically, this is not an ASCII-only issue, as much as it is a non URL-safe character issue. URLs can be unicode, so there's tons of non-ASCII characters that are perfectly fine.

The [`System.Runtime.Extensions` NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Extensions/) provides urlencoding which should be supported in .NET Standard 1.0+.